# VS: Reconcile after Gated-Checkin although the completed build already is deleted

Tags: tfsbuild, workspace

I queued a build in the evening. after my build finished there were more than 10 builds and my was already deleted. I didn't receive the reconcile message box too.

How can i now reconcile my workspace?

Answer (score 0):

The "reconcile workspace" message box is part of [Build Notification application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181725.aspx#App).

Try to remove the builds from the notification, close all VS instances, clear the TFS cache in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Cache`, and re-lunch VS. VS should make Build Notification application run automatically, if it doesn't run automatically, try to re-run it.

Comment: Unfortunately clearing my TFS cache broke the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl functionality(i have some add-ons installed). The error i get after clearing the cache: "The type 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workspace' exists in both 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll' and 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll'" and i cant load the workspaces....

Comment: Did you reference the assembly in cache folder? Clearing cache folder shouldn't effect your project. You should use Nuget to restore the package automatically.

Comment: I wonder too why it has such an effect. But i referenced it from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.dll". (From Reference Manager -> Extensions)

Comment: Try to re-reference the assembly to see whether the issue persists.